# Pan a div in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm somehow struggling to get this fixed. I'm trying to pan a DIV using in jquery. The logic is pretty simple. On mouseDown, I get X & Y and subtracting X & Y on mouseMove to pan the div.

But somehow the div is moving a lot faster and Could not understand the reason behind it.

```
$('div').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    self.panStartX = e.pageX;
    self.panStartY = e.pageY;
    self.mouseDown = true;
}).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (self.mouseDown) {
        var pageTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'), false) || 0;
        var pageLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'), false) || 0;
        self.panEndX = e.pageX;
        self.panEndY = e.pageY;

        if (self.panStartY > self.panEndY) {
            self.panTop = self.panEndY - self.panStartY;

            pageTop+= self.panTop;
            $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
        } else {
            // Down
            self.panTop = self.panStartY - self.panEndY;

            pageTop-= self.panTop;
            if (pageTop > 42) pageTop = 42;

            $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
        }
    }
}).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    self.mouseDown = false;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hvUVy/

Comment: I would write `this.offsetTop` instead of `parseInt($(this).css('top'), false)` ... granted, I didn't check IE compatibility :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is how you are calculating the `pageTop` value. You need to find the `pageTop` at mouse down and add/subtract the difference

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var self = {};

    $('div').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        self.panStartX = e.pageX;
        self.panStartY = e.pageY;
        self.mouseDown = true;
        self.pageTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'), false) || 0;
        self.pageLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'), false) || 0;
    }).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (self.mouseDown) {
            var pageTop = self.pageTop;
            var pageLeft = self.pageLeft;
            self.panEndX = e.pageX;
            self.panEndY = e.pageY;

            if (self.panStartY > self.panEndY) {
                self.panTop = self.panEndY - self.panStartY;

                pageTop+= self.panTop;

                $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
            } else {
                // Down
                self.panTop = self.panStartY - self.panEndY;

                pageTop-= self.panTop;
                if (pageTop > 42) pageTop = 42;

                $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
            }
        }
    }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        self.mouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EKVJc/)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the *if* statment with :

```
        $(this).css({ top:  self.panEndY - self.panStartY });            
        /*if (self.panStartY > self.panEndY) {
            self.panTop = self.panEndY - self.panStartY;

            pageTop= self.panTop;
            $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
        } else {
            // Down
            self.panTop = self.panStartY - self.panEndY;

            pageTop= self.panTop;
            if (pageTop > 42) pageTop = 42;

            $(this).css({ top: pageTop });
        }*/
```

Comment: its moving the page on top on every pan